# How to clip CAGradientLayer with mask?

Tags: ios, swift

I draw mask layer with `UIBezeirPath` and create `CAGradientLayer` with some `rect` position, after that I wants to clip gradient by this mask and use:

```
let mask = CAShapeLayer()
mask.path = path.cgPath
let gradient = CAGradientLayer()
...
gradient.mask = mask
```

but when two line cross I see that mask not clip gradient by path.

[image]